# No data shown after I imported a csv file to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I have imported a CSV file to MySQL, but there is no data shown. How can I solve it?

This is my table
[image]

Comment: importing files has many options that can be manipulated, but for that you must know how the data looks like and how your sql import string looks like

Answer (score 0):

The data may be corrupted. I have had to convert a csv file to xml before to edit the data so that it could be parsed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).